# Как сделать перемещение объекта при изменении размера экрана?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как правильно сделать перемещение объекта по горизонтали при изменении экрана. Я сделал вертикальное так:

```
let asideMenuLink1 = document.querySelector('.aside__menu-link1')
selectedTab = document.querySelector('.selected-tab')

asideMenuLink1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
selectedTab.style.cssText = `
transform: translateY(71px);
`
})
```

добавил условие:

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 905) {
selectedTab.style.cssText = `
transform: translateX(71px);
`
}
```

Но это не помогло. где ошибка?
Мне надо чтобы переключение между табами которое было по вертикали, стало по горизонтали при изменении экрана меньше или равном 905px.

Comment: для начала вы отслеживаете не то событие, поменяйте click на resize, если при изменении экрана вы имете ввиду ширину окна

Comment: поменял но не помогло. мне же надо чтобы при клике на следующую вкладку менялось положение объекта по горизонтали

Comment: ваш вопрос не понятен, добавьте дополнительно ваш html код и опишите более подробно, что вы хотите получить

Comment: все что я вижу, то при клике на таб у вас идет проверка ширины и при шрине менее 905px текст уйдет вправо на 71px.